# Explicitly computing the reduction of some quotient over the $5$-adics where both enumerator and denominator have the same positive valuation

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $K = \mathbb{Q}_5$ and $f = X^3 - 135X - 270 \in K[X]$.

Let $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3$ be the roots of $f$ over its splitting field $L$.

Consider the $M = \mathbb{Q}_5(\alpha_1,\sqrt{C})$ of $K$ where $C = (\alpha_2 - \alpha_1)^3$.

> **Question**: What is $\lambda := \frac{270}{C} \mod \pi_M$? (where $\pi_M$ is a uniformizer in $M$)?

**What I tried**:

- I tried to apply the technique from one of [the answer of this previous of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3745184/computing-the-reduction-of-a-quotient-over-the-5-adic-numbers/3745594#3745594). However, this technique seems to require an explicit uniformizer in that post.
- Since the ramification index of $M/K$ is $6$, I must find some element with valuation $1/6$ (note: I let my valuation satisfy $v(5) = 1$). And here, I am lost already.
- Furthermore, I know that the residue field of $M/K$ is $\mathbb{F}_5$.
- More valuations which may be helpful: It is $v(\alpha_1) = v(\alpha_2) = v(\alpha_2 - \alpha_1) = 1/3$ and $v(\sqrt{C}) = 1/2$. Hence $v(C) = 1 = v(270)$, so $\lambda \mod \pi_M$ is non-zero in $\mathbb{F}_5$.

Could you please help me with this problem? I am grateful if you could help me with the uniformizer or help me to find another approach.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you include some context about where this question is coming from, such as why you are interested in the field $M$?

Comment: I don't think the ramification index is 6. The extension you give is an extension of $\mathbb Q_5(\alpha)$ inside its splitting field, but the splitting field is unramified over that extension. So the same uniformizer works. You're also confused if you try to find something with valuation $6$ - if you want a new uniformizer and you normalize $v(5) = 1$ then you want something with the *reciprocal* valuation of $1/6$. (but I don't think there is such an element)

Comment: I haven’t checked  your computations, but: (1) It’s merely a slip on your part, but you want an element of valuation $\frac16$, not of valuation $6$; (2) Surely, if $v(\alpha_1)=\frac13$ and $v(\sqrt C\,)=\frac12$, then $v(C/\alpha_1)=\frac16$, no?

Comment: Yes @TokenToucan , I doubted the claim $e=6$, but I’m lazy tonight.

Comment: Actually, I think I could have been wrong. I mistook $C$ for the discriminant but it  isn't, so seems like this extension might not actually be inside the splitting field. But as @Lubin writes, if it has the valuation you claim (looking more likely) then $C/\alpha_1$ works.

Comment: Thanks for your remarks! I noted some of my mistakes and edited them appropriately.

Regarding the uniformizer: You probably mean that it is $\sqrt{C}/\alpha_1$, right? But I understood why the valuation would be $1/6$ then.

Comment: @KCd: I am not sure if this answer is satisfactory but there seems to be some algorithm where you can compute the Galois representation of an elliptic curve with potentially good reduction which works by computing some invariant over different fields. It is part of my research and I am trying to work out some explicit examples (that's why this seemingly random $M$ appears).

Comment: Yes, right on the application of the identity $\frac12-\frac13=\frac16$.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry it’s taken me so long, but I was too tired last night. I’ll use $(\alpha,\beta)$ instead of $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$.

First, as you probably saw, the extension $K(\alpha,\beta)=L\supset K$ has $e=3$, $f=2$. (In case you didn’t see this, we have $f(X)=(X-\alpha)\bigl(X^2+\alpha X+(\alpha^2-135)\bigr)$. If you divide the roots of the quadratic factor by $\alpha$, you get a polynomial $\equiv X^2+X+1\pmod{(\alpha)}$. Thus you need to adjoin the cube roots of unity to $\Bbb F_5$ to get the right residue-class field.)

As you recognize, $v_5(\beta-\alpha)=\frac13$, so that its cube has valuation $1$; square root of that requires a valuation of $1/2$, so your
uniformizer (element of valuation $\frac16$) is clear.

Finally, to get a good handle on your $\lambda$, I decided to work computationally over $\Bbb Q_5=K$. I defined $K(\alpha)$ as you did, but I worked with $L$ defined as $K(\alpha,\omega)$ where $\omega^2+\omega+1=0$, and found that we could take $\beta$ to be
$$
\beta=\dots043;\times5 + \dots014;\times5\alpha + \dots324;\alpha^2 + (\dots141;\times5 + \dots331;\alpha + \dots203;\alpha^2)\omega\,,
$$
where I hope you’re comfortable with $5$-ary expansion: “$\dots203;$” means $3\times5^0+0\times5^1+2\times5^2$, each notation like this to be read modulo $5^3$. Notice that, modulo $\alpha^2$, the above is $\equiv\alpha\omega$.

And now, my computation package rendered $\lambda=\frac{270}{(\beta-\alpha)^3}$ as
$$
\lambda=\dots211; + \dots323;\alpha + \dots314;\times5\alpha^2 + (\dots012; + \dots442;\alpha +\dots222;\alpha^2)\omega\,,
$$
in other words $\equiv1-\omega\pmod{(\alpha)}$, when we remember that $\alpha$ is still the uniformizer in $L$.

Last of all, notice that your $\lambda$ already is in $L$, so we don’t need to go to $M$ to describe it.

**Addendum**:
This is a significant simplification of my first answer. There, I claimed that $K\bigl(\alpha,(\beta-\alpha)^{3/2}\bigr)$ is the same as $K\bigl(\alpha,(\beta-\alpha)^{1/2}\bigr)$, an essentially insupportable claim (and likely untrue). This did not affect the applicability of my answer to your question, and it’s now gone.

Comment: I see I’ve made an error in saying that $K(\alpha,(\beta-\alpha)^{3/2})$ was same as $K(\alpha,(\beta-\alpha)^{1/2})$. I’ll look at this!

Comment: No need to apologize, I appeciate the time and effort you took to answer my question! I took my time to go through your answer and have some questions:

Regarding the first part with $e=3$, $f=2$: What do you mean by getting a polynomial $\equiv X^2+X+1$ (mod $\alpha$) by dividing the roots of the quadratic factor by $\alpha$? If I had never seen TokenToucan's answer before (which was already quite long), I would be pretty lost here. Or maybe asked differently: How could I have seen this more quickly?

More questions will follow.

Comment: Another dumb question: The uniformizer is $\sqrt{\beta-\alpha}$, right? I think you tried to convince me that it is indeed an element in $L$, and then find the appropriate uniformizer after our discussion in the comments.

Regarding $\beta$: Was there a systemic approach when you tried to find $\beta$? As someone who did not work much computationally, it also seems to come out of nowhere.

More questions will follow.

Comment: Regarding the $5$-ary expansion: I only know that every $x \in \mathbb{Z}_5$ can be written as $x = \sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k \cdot 5^k$ for $c_k \in \{0,\dots,4\}$. I guess the notation works like this $x = \dots c_3 c_2 c_1 c_0$.

However, I do not have many practical experience with this (meaning I barely had to work with explicit examples), so I am also not sure why the $\alpha$'s appear in this expansion and why we habe $\beta \equiv \alpha \omega$ (mod $\alpha^2$). I am also a bit lost at the expansion of $\lambda$.

Comment: And if this was not enough stuff to read: Could you please let me know what programming language you used?

I have minimum knowledge about Sage but I could not use it to implement my problem. Also, I heard that Sage is not so good in general (as Magma, from what I heard too).

I would be interested to learn another language if it helps me in the future. But I am not sure whether there are good learning resources for that...

Comment: Ook. (1) I would think it clear that if quadratic $X^2+\gamma bX+\gamma^2c$ has a root $\rho$, then $X^2+bX +c$ has a root $\rho/\gamma$. (2) $\sqrt{\beta-\alpha}$ is a uniformizer in the quadratic extension of $L$ that it generates. It’s not in $L$, because $e^L_K=3$. (3) I’ve been using a home-made package, very purpose-built, to let me describe elements of any particular extension of familiar fields (except $\Bbb R$ ! ) and power series whose coefficients are in such fields. Otherwise, it’s embarrassingly primitive.

Comment: And I forgot to say: If $f(X)\in k[X]$ has a root $\alpha$, then it’s of the form $(X-\alpha)g(X)$, by Euclidean division, but $g(X)\in k(\alpha)[X]$. I’m a very computationally-oriented guy, and I do recommend a serious consumption of paper and pencil-lead to all who would thoroughly understand the mathematics they’re working in.